# Session cookie issue: undefined method `each_with_object' Upgrading to Rails 4 and Ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

We are upgrading from Ruby 1.9.3 to Ruby 2 and from Rails 3.x to Rails4.
We are using devise for authentication. We upgraded the gems based on Ryan Bates Railscasts.

Now, when I start the server, I see the following error.

Update: This has something to do with session cookies, when I open a window in incognito mode I don't get this error, but I don't want my users to get this error.

I am using rbenv

```
→ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin12.0]

→ gem list rack

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)


Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `each_with_object' for #<String:0x007fe40519d368>):
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:175:in `stringify_keys'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:170:in `load!'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:160:in `load_for_read!'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:86:in `[]'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:30:in `fetch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:212:in `user'
```

Comment: have you updated Rack?

Comment: rack version is 1.5.2

Comment: It's a session cookie issue, since does not happen in incognito mode on chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by commenting out session store caching from session_store.rb

```
# Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
# which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
# (create the session table with "rails generate session_migration")

#Reports::Application.config.session_store :cache_store
```

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your session by removing cookies in your browser. If this works then you need to invalidate all sessions so this doesn't blow up for your users. You can do this by changing your `secret_key_base` in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had to turn off session caching to fix this.